# assign a variable to each data in a line separated by whitespaces

Tags: python, file-io

Basically I want to use python to read each data in the last two lines of the following file to a different variable.

The file is of the following form:

```
a b c
10
10 0 0 
2 5
xyz 
  10 12 13
  11 12 12.4
   1 34.5 10.8
```

I want the output to have the following

```
d=11, e=12, f=12.4
g=1 h =34.5 i=10.8
```

How can I loop over the lines if I have say 100 lines (after xyz) each with three data. And that I need to read only say last 3 lines in it.

The following is what I did, but doesn't seem to reach anywhere.

```
p1=open('aaa','r') 
im=open('bbb','w')
t=open('test','w')
lines=p1.readlines()


i=0
for line in lines:
    Nj=[]
    Nk=[]
    Cx=Cy=Cz=Nx=Ny=Nz=0
    i=i+1
    if line.strip():
        if i==1:
            t.write(line)
            dummy=line.strip().split()
            a1=dummy[0]
            a2=dummy[1]
            a3=dummy[2]

            print("The atoms present are %s, %s and %s" %(a1, a2,a3)) 
        if i==2:
            t.write(line)
        if i==3:
            t.write(line)
        if i==4:
            t.write(line)
        if i==5:
            t.write(line)
        if i==6:
            t.write(line)
            dummy=line.strip().split()
            Na1=dummy[0]
            Na2=dummy[1]
            Na3=dummy[2]

            import string

            N1=string.atoi(Na1)
            N2=string.atoi(Na2)
            N3=string.atoi(Na3)
            print("number of %s atoms= %d "%(a1,N1))
            print("number of %s atoms= %d "%(a2,N2))
            print("number of %s atoms= %d "%(a3,N3))

        if i==7:
                 t.write(line)
        if i==8:
                 t.write(line)


for i, line in enumerate(p1):
    if i==8:
                    dummy=line.strip().split()
                    Njx=dummy[0]
                    Njy=dummy[1]
                    Njz=dummy[2]
                    import string
                    Njx=string.atof(Njx)
                    Njy=string.atof(Njy)
                    Njz=string.atof(Njz)
                    Nj = [Njx, Njy, Njz]

    elif i==9:
                    dummy=line.strip().split()
                    Nkx=dummy[0]
                    Nky=dummy[1]
                    Nkz=dummy[2]
                    import string
                    Nkx=string.atof(Nkx)
                    Nky=string.atof(Nky)
                    Nkz=string.atof(Nkz)
                    Nk = [Nkx, Nky, Nkz]
        break
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Here if you see, Nk, Nj are locally defined. I don't know how to use these variables globally. I am sure, there must be a shorter script than mine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file's last two lines with

```
f = open(file, "r")
lines = f.readlines()[-2:] # change this if you want more than the last two lines
f.close()
split1 = lines[0].strip().split(' ') # In the example below: lines[0] = "4 5 6\n"
split2 = lines[1].strip().split(' ') # lines[1] = "7 8 9"
```

Then, you can assign those values to your variables:

```
d,e,f = [int(x) for x in split1]
g,h,i = [int(x) for x in split2]
```

This will assign the three values of each line to `d,e,f,g,h,i`, for example:

(your file)

```
...
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

(result)

```
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
g = 7
h = 8
i = 9
```

Comment: Thats amazing. Thank you :)))) I did not know what is the meaning of the quotes in split(' '). But I changed it to split() and it works fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user274642: The argument of `split` is the character you want to use as a separator. If your file contains values separated by commas (e.g. `1,2,3`), you would use `split(',')`. Because your file containes spaces between the numbers, I used a space (`' '`). The default behavior of [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is to use any whitespace as the delimiter.

Comment: where can I find more about readlines(). I mean I want to read a specific line

Comment: @user274642: [`file.readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) -- any question regarding specific built-in methods is probably answered in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    # Get two last lines, remove the '\n'
    contents = map(lambda s : s[:-1], f.readlines()[-2:])
    # Get the three last lines, 
    [[d,e,f],[g,h,i]] = map(lambda s : map(float, s.split(" ")[-3:]), contents)
    # Check the result
    print (d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

Explanation :

1. `with open("text.txt", "r") as f:` is recommended way of working with file in python, see file I/O tutorial to see why.
2. `contents = map(lambda s : s[:-1], f.readlines()[-2:])` This load the contents of `f` into a list of strings using `readlines()`, take the last two using `[-2:]`, and remove the unnecessary `'\n'` by mapping `lambda s : s[:-1]`.
3. At this point, our `contents` should contain last two lines.
4. The expression `map(lambda s : map(float, s.split(" ")[-3:]), contents)` split each of the two lines by `" "` then unpack it to the list `[[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`. The `[-3:]` here is to remove the spaces in the front.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But it throws an error "contents.split('\n')[-3:-1])
ValueError: too many values to unpack".

Comment: Does the space before `10 12 13` really exists in the file? Sorry I thought it was mistyping into StackOverflow

Comment: There are two spaces actually in the file.

Comment: Edited..
The other answer seems to be better, anyway.

Comment: Now (finally) fixed.. Check it out